# In SSMS "SQL Server Agent" sub folders are appearing twice

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SSMS 17 installed on my system, after I connected to database instance, I found sub folders of SQL Server Agent are repeating.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Never came across this. But can you try this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807502/sql-server-management-studio-17-cannot-find-one-or-more-components

Comment: Are you using the latest [17.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) version?

Comment: Are you using any add-ins?

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft No, I am not using any add-ins.